Source for the story of Insemination in pool
I heard there’s a case in the Gemara that a woman in a pool got pregnant from a man in the pool who let שכבת זרע out into the water (with no direct contact though). Anyone have the source?

Chagigah 14b:

They also asked ben Zoma: A woman considered to be a virgin who became
pregnant, what is the halakha? A High Priest may marry only a virgin;
is he permitted to marry her? ... He said to them: ... we are
concerned that she may have conceived in a bath.

It is said that Yirmiyahu's daughter was impregnated in this way.

Thanks. This just led me down a whole rabbit hole about the alphabet of Ben Sira. Do you know if this book is considered legit? The site I read said it’s a satire probably written by a heretic, but then why would it be in Otzar Midrashim and on Sefaria?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36746/6592

Note that most of the sources which quote that Ben Sira was born through an ambati don't mention the Yirmiyahu part. Only Likkutei Maharil says that, without any prior source for that assertion

@CuriousYid Alphabet's legitimacy is debatable. It's considered a medieval work, unlike Ben Sira which is from the Hellenistic period. Otzar brings it because Eisenstein brought many works of questionable origins simply because they were old or at least seemed old and seemed based on traditional hashkafa. Sefaria probably brings it for the same reason, although Sefaria isn't an inherently Orthodox site.

@Harel13 thank you
