# Neviyim and Kesuvim are Torah Shebiksav?

Tags: tanach

Nach - Neviyim and Kesuvim was written way after the revelation at Sinai. Why is it considered as part of Torah Shebiksav (written Torah) and not as Torah Shebaal Pe (Oral Torah)?

Comment: many books in the nabee'eem and kathubeem were written by a later generation.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob: and thus the question

Comment: How do you know they are so considered? What does it even mean to be considered that?

Comment: @GershonGold the mishnayoth were oral too but were written down by later generations. still considered baa3l pah.

Comment: Just for the record, there is no dagesh in the כ in בכתב.

Answer (score 1):

One difference between torah she-bi-khtav and torah she-b-al peh is form:

- a fixed, finite text, with every letter counted and the number of
  letters never changing, for torah sh-bi-khtav

versus:

- a fluid communication of meaning, with continual expansion over time,
  and continual change to meet and absorb the particularities of
  everyday life in new times and places, for torah she-b-al-peh

Nevi'im and Ktuvim have that fixed, set form (even if they have a different status than Humash)--the number of letters and words in each book set and limited and never added-to or changed.

Answer (score 0):

Torah sheBichtav refers to books written while there was still Nevua and\or the Jews lived in Israel with a Beit Mikdash.  Torah sheBaal Peh refers to anything written after the end of this holy era, and also includes any discussion and interpretation of sheBichtav.

---

Let's flip the question around:

Why is Yehoshua (and the rest of Neviim Rishonim) not part of "Torah," as they appear to be a simple continuation of the story?  If Devarim, which is Moshe's speech (and thus wasn't revealed at Sinai), is part of Torah, then why isn't Yehoshua or Shmuel, which are Yehoshua's and Shmuel's narrative and speeches, respectively?

The answer to this, and to your question, is that at some point in Jewish history some books were accepted as "super-holy" (or similar, can't really express it), and were raised to a new level.  They were then categorized as such, and no new books were allowed to be added to them.

This happened in several stages.  The first stage was for Torah, which was "closed" when the Jews entered Israel.  The second stage was for Neviim, which was closed with Churban Bayit Rishon (appx) and the end of Nevua.  And the third stage was Ketuvim, which was closed with Churban Bayit Sheini.  (This also explains why Daniel, for example, is part of Ketuvim and not Neviim.)  After the destruction of both Batei Mikdash, that era of holiness and prophecy was over, and no new books could be added to Torah sheBichtav at all.

*Source: Yeshiva University's Intro to Bible class*

Comment: Which "Intro to Bible class"? There are a number of different ones taught at that institution.

Comment: Based on notes found here: http://www.swapnotes.com/showCourseProf.jsp?cpid=823&id=4206 (registration required)

Comment: @Shmuel actually the close was the Anshei Knesses Hagedolah at the start of the second temple era. That is why Esther was accepted but there are no Kesuvim for Chanukah

Comment: @sabbahillel Perhaps. It all depends on your chronology.

Comment: Some of the neviim were in bayis sheni, such as Chagai.

Comment: @Ypnypn We don't know Chaggai lived during bayis sheni. His last recorded Nevua is the day before building started.

Comment: There *are* Kesuvim for Chanukah - Sefer haMaccabim.  Why it wasn't made part of Tanach is a separate issue.

Comment: Also, it's unclear when Esther was written\took place.  Finally, even after the Churban there was still discussion about which books are "meTamei Yadiim" etc, indicating that canonization was a process that took some time to complete.

Comment: Re Sefer haMaccabim - http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33/why-isnt-the-book-of-the-maccabees-part-of-the-jewish-canon

Comment: The Men of the Great Assembly lived right at the beginning of the Second Temple Period, not around its destrcution. They closed the Biblical Canon.

Comment: @BabySeal Then how do you explain Yadayim 3:6?

Comment: @DoubleAA the opinion is that kohelet wasn't written with Ruach hakodesh, per Bartenura,  so it was just Solomon's wisdom, given special treatment by the Men, this seems to be based on Rashi in megillah 7a, And As Song of Songs was also written by Solomon, i would say the same regarding it. In any event, the argument isn't about the biblical canon, its about The books *in* the biblical cannon's status.

Comment: @Shmuel what about Torah Shebaal Peh that has Halacha Moshe miSinai? prophecy was still going on then.

Comment: @warz3 - Sorry, I don't understand.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

[Rashi on Malacha 1:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16219#showrashi=true) "The burden of the word of the Lord to Israel in the hand of Malachi"

> "in the hand of Malachi" - [Rashi] It was already delivered into his
>   hand for many days. From here, our Sages expounded in a baraitha of
>   Mechilta that **all the prophets stood on Mount Sinai and there the
>   prophecies were delivered to them**, and so [Isaiah (48:16)] says:
>   “From the time it was, there was I, and now, the Lord God has sent me,
>   [and His spirit].”

hence, just because it was written later does not mean it did not already exist in some form.

Comment: When did the prophets stand on Mount Sinai? This Midrash seems to discuss _where_ they got their prophesies not _when_ they got them.

Comment: @DoubleAA we can assume at sinai means when all the jews were assembled there to receive the torah. if it was a different time it should have been stated explicitly.

Comment: And you think that the Oral Law _didn't_ exist 'in some form' from the time of Moshe Rabbeinu?